# var checkedValue - Jquery - how to change language?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this to extract a `checkbox` value:

```
var checkedValue = $('.messageCheckbox:checked').val();
```

However, when the checkbox is on, it displays "On", when is off, it displays nothing.

Like this:

```
Is checked (Yes): On
Is checked (No):
```

What should I change to make it appear on/off, and how can I change the language or at least edit the result's text?

Comment: `if($('.messageCheckbox').is(":checked")) { $('.messageCheckbox').val() }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
 var text = checkedValue ? 'Yes' : 'No';
 console.log(text);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/twugud15/

Comment: I doesn't work. Probably a wrong comma or something?

Comment: `var idaevolta = $('idaevolta:checked').val();
 var idaevolta = checkedValue ? 'Yes' : 'No';`
???

Comment: `var idaevolta = $('.idaevolta').val() ? 'Yes' : 'No';` https://jsfiddle.net/twugud15/3/

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
var checkedValue = $('.messageCheckbox').val();
```